# Php encrypt output with 3-8 symbols length

Tags: php, encryption

Is it possible to limit the maximum symbol length of the output `openssl_encrypt()` function with saving an opportunity to decrypt it? If no, what are the ways to encrypt a string with only 3-8 symbols output length?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the old fashioned DES algorithm in ECB mode but **DES algorithm and ECB mode are UNSECURE**.

DES has a block length of 8 bytes so the output comes into 8 byte blocks - that will work due to internal padding up to plaintexts of length 7 - having a 8 byte long plaintext causes the algorithm to append one more block of (padding) data and you end up with 16 bytes of output.

Another way would be to use **AES in mode CTR** - you will need to predefine the key AND the initialization vector (iv) used for encryption. Using a fixed iv makes this kind of encryption **UNSECURE** as well.

This is the output of the sample program (I preferred the "raw output format" because otherwise you get a base64 encoded ciphertext that has a (minimum) length of 12 characters):

```
### Security warning - the code is UNSECURE

DES encryption example

des encryption with plaintext: 123
ciphertext len: 8 data: N��K=���
decryptedtext: 123

des encryption with plaintext: 1234567
ciphertext len: 8 data: �;[��,q
decryptedtext: 1234567

des encryption with plaintext: 12345678
ciphertext len: 16 data: �V�@�Ա���qhJc�
decryptedtext: 12345678
```

code:

```
<?php
echo '### Security warning - the code is UNSECURE' . PHP_EOL;
echo PHP_EOL . 'DES encryption example' .PHP_EOL;
$key = '12348765'; // des-key = 8 bytes ### don't hardcode a key in code !!
$plaintext = '123';
echo PHP_EOL . 'des encryption with plaintext: ' . $plaintext . PHP_EOL;
$ciphertext = openssl_encrypt($plaintext, 'des-ecb', $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA);
echo 'ciphertext len: ' . strlen($ciphertext) . ' data: ' . $ciphertext . PHP_EOL;
$decryptedtext = openssl_decrypt($ciphertext, 'des-ecb', $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA);
echo 'decryptedtext: ' . $decryptedtext . PHP_EOL;

$plaintext = '1234567';
echo PHP_EOL . 'des encryption with plaintext: ' . $plaintext . PHP_EOL;
$ciphertext = openssl_encrypt($plaintext, 'des-ecb', $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA);
echo 'ciphertext len: ' . strlen($ciphertext) . ' data: ' . $ciphertext . PHP_EOL;
$decryptedtext = openssl_decrypt($ciphertext, 'des-ecb', $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA);
echo 'decryptedtext: ' . $decryptedtext . PHP_EOL;

$plaintext = '12345678';
echo PHP_EOL . 'des encryption with plaintext: ' . $plaintext . PHP_EOL;
$ciphertext = openssl_encrypt($plaintext, 'des-ecb', $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA);
echo 'ciphertext len: ' . strlen($ciphertext) . ' data: ' . $ciphertext . PHP_EOL;
$decryptedtext = openssl_decrypt($ciphertext, 'des-ecb', $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA);
echo 'decryptedtext: ' . $decryptedtext . PHP_EOL;
?>
```

Comment: But what if the length of a string (plain text) is not constant? From two symbols up to one hundred two, the encrypted result must meet the limit of 3-8 symbols length.

Comment: Did you ever heard about a zip-function that is been able to shrink 102 characters to a maximum of 8? Or do you mean to encrypt in Chunks of (each) 8 bytes length?

Comment: First one. Didn't heard about that. Can you please provide doc for that? Also, what if I need less than 8?

Comment: To let you understand better.
Input: 
a) text
b) biggertexxxxt
c) reallylongtexxxxxxxxxxt ;
Output:
a) au2zXYz
b) jgZY5
c) ajjnfua8 ;

Other way:
Input:
a) au2zXYz
b) jgZY5
c) ajjnfua8 ;
Output:
a) text
b) biggertexxxxt
c) reallylongtexxxxxxxxxxt

Comment: As the output length of an encryption ("ciphertext") is (minimum) equal to the input length (in most cases some bytes are added for padding) there is **no encryption scheme** that fulfills your expectation, sorry. Or to answer your question in short: NO.